# VBA for Excel. How to get rid of Error 91 when loading a form again

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a bit new and a bit old with VBA.

I have 2 lists of students (boys and girls) that I call randomly by reordering their names. However, when one list is shorter I'd like VBA to select range 2 (the first student) again so that they can continue answering questions. However, when it's loaded again, I get error 91 :/

I have a form for showing names of students and another to show questions. The problem is in the initialize event. This is the code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim NUEVAPOSICIONb As range
Dim NUEVAPOSICIONg As range


Form_00_ListaDeAlumnos.Width = ActiveWindow.Width    'IGUALA ANCHO    FORMULARIO A ANCHO DE EXCEL
Form_00_ListaDeAlumnos.Height = Application.Height    ''IGUALA ALTO   FORMULARIO A ALTO DE EXCEL

'PONE TODOS LOS TABSTOPS Y FOCUSONCLICK EN FALSE
On Error Resume Next
For i = 0 To Controls.Count - 1   ' Use the Controls collection
Controls(i).TabStop = False
Controls(i).TakeFocusOnClick = False
Next

''SI DICE CHICOS
If Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("WHOSE TURN   IS IT?").range(2) = "BOYS" Then
Form_00_ListaDeAlumnos.BackColor = vbBlue
Label1.BackColor = vbBlue
'CAMBIA EL SEXO PARA EL PROXIMO EQUIPO:CHICAS
Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("WHOSE TURN IS IT?").range(2) = "GIRLS"
Set NUEVAPOSICIONb =      Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("Position of Boys").range(2)
'SELECCIONA POSICION DE TABLA DE CHICOS, FILA APELLIDO Y NOMBRES
Sheets("Lista Primer Trimestre").Select
Sheets("Lista Primer   Trimestre").ListObjects("LISTA_1T_CHICOS").ListColumns("APELLIDO Y NOMBRE").range(NUEVAPOSICIONb).Select


''SI DICE CHICAS
ElseIf Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("WHOSE TURN IS IT?").range(2) = "GIRLS" Then
Form_00_ListaDeAlumnos.BackColor = vbRed
Label1.BackColor = vbRed
'CAMBIA EL SEXO PARA EL PROXIMO EQUIPO:CHICOS
Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("WHOSE TURN IS IT?").range(2) = "BOYS"
Set NUEVAPOSICIONg =   Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("Position of Girls").range(2)
'SELECCIONA ENCABEZADO DE TABLA DE CHICOS, FILA APELLIDO Y NOMBRES
Sheets("Lista Primer Trimestre").Select
Sheets("Lista Primer   Trimestre").ListObjects("LISTA_1T_CHICAS").ListColumns("APELLIDO Y NOMBRE").range(NUEVAPOSICIONg).Select
End If

'PARA QUE CADA VEZ QUE VENGA A BUSCAR A UN CHICO SIGA EL SIGUIENTE
'SI HAY DATOS DEBAJO
If Selection.Offset(1, 0) <> Empty Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
TextBox1_Nombre.Text = Selection
'COPIAR QUIÉN FUE SELECCIONADO EN UNA CELDA EN SETTINGS
sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("Chosen_student").range(2) = Selection

ElseIf Selection.Offset(1, 0) = Empty Then
'SI NO QUEDAN MÁS ALUMNOS
MsgBox "All Students have been chosen"
Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("WHOSE TURN IS IT?").range(2) = "BOYS"
Sheets("Settings").ListObjects("WHOSETURNISIT").ListColumns("Position of   Boys").range(2) = 1
Set NUEVAPOSICIONb.Value = 2
Set NUEVAPOSICIONg.Value = 2

Unload Me
load_Form_00_ListaDeAlumnos
End If


End Sub
```

Here your a link to download the file: [My file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4R1PgNMC67fQi1BRjRuUmZYSkE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: If you press `F8` to run the code line by line, which line produces the error?

Comment: It is not a good idea to unload a form while it is still loading.

Comment: Please comment on `On Error Resume Next` in your code so that you get error messages. It's impossible to trouble-shoot something like this if errors aren't being displayed. This is something that should never be used for more than one or two lines of code, for a very special reason!

Comment: I also recommend you [tag:edit] your code to make it more easily readable. You need to indent things, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'll try those things  :) Thank you so much for such quick responses. 
It's great to have you as my teachers since I never studied with anybody but by myself reading and watching videos. But I really spend lots of hours and sometimes don't sleep in order to try new things to solve my problems.

I tried not to unload the form in the initialize and it worked. The error dissapeared. I wrote that code within a button click event and I got what I wanted :) However, I had to change some things again in the initialize. It's incredible how different ways can lead to same results:D